# Where to initialise variable that's needed in initState() in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a the following method:

```
 getCalendarEventList() async {
    print('here we go agsain');
     await Firestore.instance.collection('availableDates').where('bandId', isEqualTo: identifier).snapshots().listen(
            (data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => _markedDateMap.add(
            doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
            Event(
                date:doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
                title: 'hello',
                icon: _presentIcon(doc['availableDates'].toDate().day.toString())))));
    setState(() {});
  }
```

The `firebase` query contains `isEqualTo: identifier` as a condition. `Identifier` is a `String` which is actually the the Firebase `uid` of the user. The getCalendarEventList() is called in `initState()`:  Because I want the the [calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel) to be populated with markers

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCalendarEventList();
  }
```

I have a method: that gets the `firebase` `uid`:

```
Future<String> inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid.toString();
    return uid;
  }
```

I've put  `identifier = await inputData();` in the `getCalendarEventList()` and 9/10 times the markers populate the calendar..(from `initState()`) So it's a bit 'buggy' ..I think this has to do with calling the uid from Firebase. Where/How should I initialise the variable `identifier` with the `firebase uid`?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is call the identifier and then when that's done, you can then call the `getCalenderEvents()`.

```
   await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
     Firestore.instance.collection('availableDates').where('bandId', isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots().listen(
            (data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) => _markedDateMap.add(
            doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
            Event(
                date:doc['availableDates'].toDate(),
                title: 'hello',
                icon: _presentIcon(doc['availableDates'].toDate().day.toString())))));
    setState(() {});
    }).catchError((onError){
    handleError();
   });
```

or

```
   await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
    setState(() {
    identifier = user.uid;
   });
    getCalenderEvents();
    }).catchError((onError){
    handleError();
   });
```

Comment: still the same problem.But maybe this isn't the issue.

Comment: what exactly is the problem

Comment: Dates are added to `_markedDateMap` in the  `getCalenderEvents();` and this class circles  the calendar ui. It works intermittently.